# null escaped in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, express

```
I console.log("var = " + JSON.stringify(result.something));
```

I got `var = null`

but when I do

```
if(result.something !=null || result.something != ''){
console.log('enter')
}
```

it print enter also. I wonder why is that happening, I also tried result.something != 'null', it still go into the if statement.

Comment: Basics of boolean operations... 
`something !=null && result.something != ''`

Comment: `null != ''` is `true`. `false || true` is `true`.

Comment: How about `if(result.something)` as false,0 (zero),"" (empty string),null,undefined,NaN will not pass this test..

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is **null**, here's why:

```
 1. (result.something !=null) : returns false

 2. (result.something != '')  : returns true
```

Since you've used an OR operator, program control is going to go inside the *if* block if either of the condition is true.

As your 2nd condition is evaluating to be *true*, it's going inside of the *if* block.

From javascript MDN:

> null : "an empty value"     i.e no object value present

null value is different from an empty string. So something like `if(null ==== " ")` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

your `if` statement always true because

the `result.something` is null **AND** it is not an empty string `null != ''`

:)